# Break Dojo Query after first match

Tags: dojo

I am using

```
     var tab =  dojo.query("[widgetid^='pvr_widget_TabContainer'][0]",toolbar.domNode.parentNode)[0];
```

and the reason i want first element only is some of the childs are like 
pvr_widget_TabContainer_0_button1 etc which holds true for my condition,

so I dont want to traverse them , can I just break the query after getting first element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selector "first-of-type" with inside the dojo.query .

Would look like this:

```
var tab =  dojo.query("[widgetid^='pvr_widget_TabContainer']:first-of-type");
```

I Have a JSFIDDLE  prepared for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/anmos5r8/